# Horizontal asymptotes of y = 1/f(x)

Tags: functions, asymptotics

If $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote of $y=a$ then the graph of $y = 1/f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote of $y=1/a$.

However what happens if $y=f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote of $y=0$. I'm thinking there's no horizontal asymptote for $y = 1/f(x)$, as $y=1/0$ is undefined.

Is this thinking correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Consider the example where f(x)= 1/x which has an asymptote at x= 0,  Then 1/f(x)= x which has no asymptote.

Comment: Consider the example $y=\exp x$.  What do you know about its horizontal asymptote and that of its reciprocal?

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct iff we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=L$$ in which case if $L=0$ then $y=1/f(x)$ will have no horizontal asymptote. However, there exist functions other than rational functions that have horizontal asymptotes, like exponential functions and the arctangent function;  notice that you cannot make the same assumption since the statement above does not apply to these functions.